# Error during Windows install

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation

***Dear Superusers,***

I need some help with Windows installation. I have been trying to install the Windows 10 operation system from a USB stick (installer downloaded from Microsoft.com), but I keep getting a 0x8007025D error code and I am puzzled why.
The installer copies all the files, the action completes, and when it tries to install them, it goes until 89%, where the attached error message comes up.
This is a fresh install, there is no running op. system on the machine.
I have a partition created for the system, it's 169 GB large. I tried to troubleshoot this, and I arrived until command line, where I saw that there wasn't any volume on it. Should I create a volume? If yes, how can I do it from the command line?

[image: installation error message]

Comment: This is an English only website.  Please translate teh message and post ias text in your question.

Comment: When I encounter issues like this, I typically, just download the ISO again and recreate the installation media. However, without an English translation of the error, it will be difficult to provide assistance

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Sorry for the error message, here is the translation: "Windows can not install the files needed. Please make sure that all files necessary for the installation are available, and start the installation again."

Comment: 0x8007025D = ERROR_BAD_COMPRESSION_BUFFER so you need to format & chkdsk both the drive you are installing on and the usb stick

Comment: https://www.auslogics.com/en/articles/fix-error-code-0x8007025d-in-windows-10/#:~:text=The%200x8007025D%20Windows%20Setup%20error,via%20a%20USB%20flash%20drive.    ...   Your download media may be bad or the wrong type for your use.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound and Gantendo, either of your answers helped, because I downloaded an ISO and created the boot USB from that, and I also repartitioned and formatted the target partition, and finally it worked out! Thank you! Can I mark your answers as soultion somehow?

Comment: @SalvadorBali - You should submit an answer instead of answering your own question with a comment.